# no returning value into console.log while using fs.read

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help in reading a text file, `information.txt`, and show the values using `console.log`.

This is the code:

```
fs.readFileSync("information.txt", "utf-8", function (err, data) {                                                                                         
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  var content = data;
  console.log(content);
});
```

Comment: `Sync` versions of functions do not take callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in your code, this is a working version:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var content = fs.readFileSync("themes", "utf-8");
console.log(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use callbacks in synchronous functions.

So, modify the function:

```
fs.readFile("information.txt", "utf-8", function (err, data) { 
  if (err) { 
    throw err; 
  } 

  var content = data; 
  console.log(content); 
});
```